# Writing a specific line from one text file to other text file using c#

Tags: c#

I Am using sharp develop. I am making a Win App using C# . I want my program check a text file named test in drive c:  and find the line which contains "=" and then write this line to other newly created text file in drive c: .

Comment: Do you wish to only output the first line with a "=" or all such lines? If there are no "=" in the source file do you wish the destination file to be rewritten but empty or just left alone?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
File.WriteAllLines(destinationFileName,
    File.ReadAllLines(sourceFileName)
        .Where(x => x.Contains("=")));
```

Comment: Boss, is `.Where(x => x.Contains("=")` is a lambda expression?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple way using `File.ReadLines`, Linq's `Where` and `File.AppendAllLines`

```
var path1 = @"C:\test.txt";
var path2 = @"C:\test_out.txt";

var equalLines = File.ReadLines(path1)
                     .Where(l => l.Contains("="));
File.AppendAllLines(path2, equalLines.Take(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\destinationFile.txt"))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\sourceFile.txt");

    string line = String.Empty;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("=")) { sw.WriteLine(line)); }
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: You have not closed `file` object of `StreamReader` class and you have closed `sw` object which didn't need closing since it is wrapped by `using`. Please correct these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something?

Here are two ways to read a file:

1. Use static methods available in File class. ReadAllLines to be specific. This is good enough if you are dealing with small files. Next, once you have the array, just find the item with "=" using LINQ or by any other iteration method. Once you got the line, again use File class to create and write data to the file.
2. If you are dealing with large files, use Stream. Rest remains fairly same.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (File.Exists(txtBaseAddress.Text))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtBaseAddress.Text);
    string line;
    string fileText = "";
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("="))
        {
            fileText += line;
        }
    } 
    sr.Close();
    if (fileText != "")
    {
        try
        {

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtDestAddress.Text);
            sw.Write(fileText);
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit edited Furqan's answer

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Username\Documents\a.txt"))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Username\Documents\b.txt"))
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line = String.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("="))
        {
           sw.WriteLine(line);

           if (++counter == 4)
           {
              sw.WriteLine();
              counter = 0;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and if i want to give an empty line after reading and writing the four lines then ???